# Unable to use spring cloud api gateway

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka

I am working on a sample poc and I am trying to integrate the spring cloud api gateway

In my pom.xml I have

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.tek</groupId>
<artifactId>gatewayApplication</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>Gateway Application</name>
<description>Gateway Application for Spring Boot</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>2021.0.3</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
            <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-gateway</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

and in my application.yml I have

```
       server:
  port: 9191

spring:
  application:
    name: API-GATEWAY
  cloud:
    gateway:
      routes:
        - id: DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
          uri: lb://DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
          predicates:
            - Path=/departments/**
        - id: USER-SERVICE
          uri: lb://USER-SERVICE
          predicates:
              - Path=/user/**
```

In my main class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class GatewayApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

[image: my eureka server]

**I am able to access the services directly from their respective ports , But when I try to access the api's from port gateway port ie 9191, I get**

***2022-09-08 16:23:34.644 ERROR 4128 --- [ctor-http-nio-3] a.w.r.e.AbstractErrorWebExceptionHandler : [7e6c1cec-3]  500 Server Error for HTTP GET "/user/getUserDepartment/1"
java.net.UnknownHostException: Failed to resolve 'xxxxxxxx' after 5 queries
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1047) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException:
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.cloud.gateway.filter.WeightCalculatorWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.reactive.server.MetricsWebFilter [DefaultWebFilterChain]
*__checkpoint ⇢ HTTP GET "/user/getUserDepartment/1" [ExceptionHandlingWebHandler]
Original Stack Trace:
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.finishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1047) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.tryToFinishResolve(DnsResolveContext.java:1000) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.query(DnsResolveContext.java:418) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext.access$600(DnsResolveContext.java:66) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsResolveContext$2.operationComplete(DnsResolveContext.java:467) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:578) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners0(DefaultPromise.java:571) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:550) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:491) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setValue0(DefaultPromise.java:616) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.setFailure0(DefaultPromise.java:609) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.tryFailure(DefaultPromise.java:117) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext.tryFailure(DnsQueryContext.java:256) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsQueryContext$4.run(DnsQueryContext.java:208) ~[netty-resolver-dns-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.PromiseTask.runTask(PromiseTask.java:98) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledFutureTask.java:153) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:174) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:167) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:503) ~[netty-transport-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30) ~[netty-common-4.1.79.Final.jar:4.1.79.Final]
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
Caused by: io.netty.resolver.dns.DnsNameResolverTimeoutException: [/xxxxxxx] query via UDP timed out after 5000 milliseconds (no stack trace available)**

*
Application.yml file of DepartmentService

```
server:
  port: 9001
spring:
  application:
    name: DEPARTMENT-SERVICE
  eureka:
    client:
      register-witheureka: true
      fetch-registry: true
      service-url:
        defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/
    instance:
      hostname: localhost
      prefer-ip-address: true
```

Comment: Can you specify the routes file where you have specified the URL for DEPARTMENT-SERVICE? Do you have the cloud gateway service on Github to take a look at entire project?

Comment: Are you asking about the department service controller rest end point @VeeraraghavanN

Comment: @VeeraraghavanN the routing information is already added in the application.yml of the gatewayserver

Answer (score 2):

I solved it by adding `eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true` and `eureka.instance.prefer-ip-address=true` in application.properties of all the microservices which are using the gateway service.